# PHP GD doesnt support a specifc image, any solution/workaround?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

If I run

```
 $res=imagecreatefromJPEG ('http://www.theweddingoutlet.com/core/media/media.nl?id=29428&c=697473&h=8320018df7b40ec6eff8');
```

I get False + error : gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: (no further details).

What is wrong with this specific image that makes it unsupported by GD?
How can I make GD support it? any workaround (I cant change the image)
My GD code support many similar images without issue.

GD info:
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support  enabled
FreeType Linkage  with freetype
FreeType Version  2.2.1
GIF Read Support  enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support  enabled
PNG Support  enabled
WBMP Support  enabled
XBM Support  enabled

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it was netsuite setting.

Answer (score 3):

The URL 'http://www.theweddingoutlet.com/core/media/media.nl?id=29428&c=697473&h=8320018df7b40ec6eff8' points to a non-existing resource and is as such not a valid JPEG file.

'http://www.theweddingoutlet.com/core/media/media.nl?id=29428' on the other hand *does* exist. Try that instead.

EDIT: That's funny, once you click on the second link, the first link starts working magically... some sort of server trickery going on here... In any case, just use the second URL with the id parameter.

EDIT2: @ zaf you are right. However (bear with me) if you go to:

http://www.theweddingoutlet.com/core/media/media.nl

And then to (or the original URL for that matter):

http://www.theweddingoutlet.com/core/media/media.nl?id=29428

It works :)

Comment: Your second URL is also a PAGE NOT FOUND.

Comment: Ha Ha Ha, the funniest is that NetSuite are advertising on SO ! FAIL! http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs/7545